# Flash AS3, is text anti-aliasing controlled by code?

Tags: actionscript-3, text, fonts, antialiasing, embedded-fonts

Is text anti-aliasing controlled by code, or is it embedded? What I want to do is take a swf file that someone else has made, find all of the text in the swf file and change all of the anti-aliasing modes from animation to readability. Does it work that way in as3? I honestly haven't tried any anti-aliasing in code yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can set the antiAliasType of a textfield to 'advanced', which gives you fine control over sharpness and thickness.  however, the fonts must be embedded (inclusive: the textfield must have embedFonts set to true, the TextFormat objects must have font properties exactly equal to the fontName of the embedded font, and the fonts must be already compiled).  so technically 'is it possible?' - yes.  is it likely to work the way you want it to?  no, unless you plan on working with a swiff that you know is using embedded fonts already.  then you'll need to grab all the textfields from the loaded swiff (you could use something like this: http://upshots.org/?p=107, then use array.filter to get back only TextField objects), then apply your logic.

EDIT: adding code sample

```
// assuming you're using the DisplayList class linked above
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("textfields.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler, false, 0, true);
loader.load(request);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void{

    var content:DisplayObjectContainer = event.target.loader.content as DisplayObjectContainer;
    addChild(content);

    var children:Array = new DisplayList(content);
    children = children.filter(function(item:Object, index:int, array:Array):Boolean {
        return item is TextField;
    });
    children.forEach(function(item:Object, index:int, array:Array):void {
        var textfield:TextField = item as TextField;
        textfield.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        textfield.sharpness = 100;
        textfield.thickness = 100;
    });
}
```

just ran a quick test - works as described.

Comment: that is freakin awesome. For what I am planning the fonts will always be embedded I believe. What I'm planning is to take a swf that has been generated by InDesign and modify it. I'm not sure what sort of code it embeds into them, but I plan to find out.

Comment: sounds good.  did you need a code sample how to apply the antialiasing, or are you set?

Comment: if you'd like to provide one that'd be great!

Comment: hmmmm... I appear to not be having any success. I'm not getting errors, but it's also not changing the text. I tried throwing in some trace statements to see what may or may not be working, and so far all I can determine is that if I put a trace after "return item is TextField;", the trace doesn't appear. You're using script I don't know yet so I don't really know what the problem is. I threw a trace in the displaylist function and it is finding all of the elements in the swf and can tell it's static text.

Comment: i did a trace children just before children.forEach and it doesn't trace anything..

Comment: hmmm... looks like the problem is indesign doesn't export textFields, but rather staticText objects.

Comment: i don't think it's possible to convert a StaticText object into a TextField - i looked into grabbing all it's properties and attempting to recreate it as a normal TextField, but it doesn't appear to have methods like getTextFormat (that we'd need to get the font), so that doesn't like viable.  Is there a setting in inDesign where you can make sure the textfields are 'dynamic' (standard TextField objects) on export?

Comment: At the moment, no. I'm actually attempting to contact adobe about this. I don't know if they'll actually do or give me anything, but it's worth a shot. I had really good plans for how to integrate indesign use. I've gone through all the help files, posted in a variety of forums, looked into InDesign scripting, and contacted adobe directly. So far no joy, but maybe adobe will come back to me with something. I really really appreciate your help. Even if I don't get this to work I'll be saving the code you gave me because it's still awesome and I can see it coming in handy.

Comment: sadly, the only communication I've been able to have is with a tech support person who was not able to help. They're only trained in existing options and not knowledgeable on the inner workings. I'm going to make other attempts to contact adobe, but the best I've been able to find is their contact forms which are most likely fruitless. :( well I guess I can just use text with bad anti-aliasing, but I think it is not a good option. Perhaps I can find a way of getting text fields in a swf into the indesign program that I load the text in dynamically.. Theres an idea.

Comment: I may explore the idea of having the code strip out the staticText objects and replace with textFields that have all the same values.